# Is it possible to bind to an private variables exposed property?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I don't know if this is possible or not, but here is the code to explain the question in the title:

```
public class LogicClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String _myText;
    public String MyText
    {
        get{return _myText;}
        set
        {
            _myText = value; 
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyText"));
        }
    }
    ...
}

public partial class Window1: Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private LogicClass _logic;
    public String LogicText
    {
        get{return _logic.MyText;}
    }
    ...
}

<ContentControl Name="contentControl1" >
    <Binding ElementName="MainWindow" Path="LogicText"/>
</ContentControl>
```

Is there any way to make this work, without having to expose my `LogicClass` variable and make use of its implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I guess I want to know if this can bubble up, or anything other than having to have a redundant `set` in my UI code-behind (which is how I am doing this now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to either handle the PropertyChanged event from _logic and then raise an equivalent PropertyChanged notification on LogicText, or you need to add a standard event on MyText, so you would have a MyTextChanged event, handle this and then raise the PropertyChanged for LogicText.

So if LogicClass if never bound to directly in the Xaml, you wouldn't need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on LogicClass and you would do (something like) this:

```
public class LogicClass
{
    private String _myText;

    public event EventHandler MyTextChanged;

    public String MyText
    {
        get{return _myText;}
        set
        {
            _myText = value; 
            var handler = MyTextChanged;
            if(handler != null){ MyTextChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty); }
        }
    }
    ...
}

public partial class Window1: Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private LogicClass _logic;

    public Window1()
    {
       _logic = ... initialised;
       _logic.MyTextChanged += (s,e) => RaisePropertyChanged("LogicText");
    }


    public String LogicText
    {
        get{return _logic.MyText;}
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I did not think about that. :-p

Answer (score 1):

If what you're asking is if you can essentially say "this property represents another property on another class, so you need to look and see if it changes" in some declarative fashion, then no, that's not possible. You can, however, mimic this behavior yourself. Just attach to the `PropertyChanged` event on your logic class and when the `MyText` property changes, raise the window's `PropertyChanged` event by calling `OnPropertyChanged`.

Note that this is almost certainly better suited to something that goes in your `ViewModel`, not something in the codebehind on the window.